# How raise an event in the viewmodel of the actual landing page, when it is triggered from a menu item in the view of the main page?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

In both view models, main page and landing page, there are the same methods called 'SaveEntry'. if the menu item is clicked, implemented in the view of main page, in the case, that the main page is active, the method 'SaveEntry' in the main view model has to execute.
In the other case, when the landing page is active and I click the menu item in the main view, then the method 'SaveEntry'in the view model landing page has to execute.

The navigation from the main page to the landing page is implemented by a routed event:

`MainContentFrame.NavigateToType(typeof(WriteEntryPage), null, navOptions);`

How I can implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you could use [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) as the navigation to process the page navigate, bind the loaded event with Command then execute `SaveEntry` in View Model when the page was loaded.

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ViewLoadedCommand}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand ViewLoadedCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ViewLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveEntry);
    }


    private void SaveEntry()
    {
        // save entry.
    }
}
```

I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/NavigationViewParameter) please refer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm using your code samples to understand the whole. It will take some time

Comment: Well, if you have any question please post as comment below.

Comment: Nico, the child is born now. The solution that I need is a mixt between your solution and the solution, how lets initiate the object 'WriteEntryViewModel' which i can access from the shellpage for execute a methode and have also access to the data, which are updated from the Ui elements of the WriteEntry view. Thanks a lot for your help.